# Image to 2D-int-array conversion javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

How to convert an image (jpeg) to a 2 dimensional int array[x][y], where x is picture width and y height in px, so that each int represents a pixel.

The image is given on a site and we are doing the conversion using a userscript in tempermonkey (chrome):

```
<img src="/image.jpeg">
```

The code should be only javascript.

Although this is a specific case, the solution should work for any client side image data manipulation where such a conversion is needed.

It is ok to do a type conversion 1st (like jpeg to bmp) or save it in a canvas we create and get a dataURL or something similar and convert to an int array from there.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please don't ask others to solve problems for you when you haven't given it a genuine try. Also, make sure you search before posting. [getImageData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) and [ImageData.data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData/data)

Comment: I've done something semi-similar before. I believe I used a canvas.

Comment: What do you mean by 'represents a pixel'? A pixel usually consits of multiple int values.

Comment: Yes. @user1983983 is right. There would not be an int representing a pixel, but an array of ints. (Probably representing the rgb values).

Comment: I've been searching for a while and I haven't found any code or even a concept how this could work in javascript. I found solutions for java and some other languages. So i have no idea where to start, and what could work.

Comment: [This is a website I have used before.](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/) Try the tutorials a bit.

Comment: For the pixel problem: A int is large enough to cover 3*8bit values, so we could just put them together like (redbits)(greenbits)(bluebits), we could also make a int[x][y][3] array or we could convert it to gif format i think it has only 255 colours. Anything works for me, since i'm working with low quality pictures and once i have integers I can make my own structure.

Comment: The possibilities are endless. I think HTML5 has some cool stuff built in, but however you want to do it is up to you!

Comment: @DanHogan This link you gave. If i read that code right - it's possible to go trough canvas data pixel by pixel? Then that should solve the problem. Once I write the code i can post the answer myself (since there is no such problem on stackoverflow yet).